# How to play a video and capture the frames from it using java

Tags: java

How to play a video and capture the frames from it using java....I want to select a particular video by browsing in a dialog box... and then play it and want to capture the frames from that video.... using java

Comment: It is a good question, useful for everyone and future visitors. Stop raping people by asking what they did so far. Good universal general questions need not be narrowed down by specific user experience.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I think it would be simpler to retrieve the frames directly from video file.

Comment: don't give assignments here,, it is not google....

Comment: What do you want the frames to become? eg png images? When you say "play a video and capture the frames" do you really want to play it (i.e. display it on the screen), or just convert the video. Do you want all the frames to end up as images (could be a lot of images)

Answer (score 3):

You should use JMF - Java Media Framework. Take a look on this reference:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html

It contains download links and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps.

- Decode the video.  You'll have to create or find a decoder for every type of video you want to play.  Here's a good Wikipedia article on [video codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec) to get you started.
- Capture each frame from the video as an Image
- Store the images on the disk.

You'll also have to build a complete Java Swing GUI to manage your video files and your image files.  This [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) should get you started learning Java Swing.

Oh, one last thought.  Every second of video produces around 32 images.  You might want to put an option in your process to only save every 10th frame, every 100th frame, or even every 1,000th frame.